# Google Analytics: Can I use custom dimension name instead of index when sending data?

Tags: indexing, google-analytics, dimensions

According to Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets), when sending data for custom dimensions or metrics, I have to use their index to identify them, like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension15':  'My Custom Dimension'
});
```

or

```
ga('set', 'dimension5', 'custom data');
```

I need to know if it's possible to send the data by using the dimension's name (i.e.: "MyDimension") instead of the index. I need to do this in a code that is used by multiple customers, and some already have other custom dimensions defined, while other customers don't. If I were able to target the custom dimension names, I wouldn't have to complicate myself with using different dimension indexes for each customer.

Comment: no its not you have to send the index number like you have done.

Comment: You could also use the customDimensions.list() method to look up a particular custom dimension by name.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#collection) and metric values are sent to Google Analytics at collection time as a pair of index and value parameters. The index parameter corresponds to the index of the custom dimension or metric defined in the Configuration phase.

```
// Set value for custom dimension at index 1.
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Level 1');
```

That's directly from the documentation you need to use the index number.

**Update from comment.** You cant just send a Json The tracking code uses the Measurement protocol directly the measurement protocol requires that you send the dimension index.  you cant hack this.   [Measurement protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs)

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking that there might be a workaround that I didn't notice. Maybe sending a JSON instead or I don't know. I have a proprietary webshop platform, and we were sending data to some custom variables. Now that I am upgrading to universal analytics, I notice that it's not as easy to just send that data, because some customers already have custom dimensions in their accounts, while others don't. Which means that I can't indiscriminately send data to the same 'dimension:1' because that will be a different dimension based on the customer's setup.

Comment: In that case why not query there account and see what custom dimensions they have set up?    https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list

Comment: What would you recommend? I have almost 700 customers, and I need to handle these custom dimensions for all of them.

Comment: Your  going to need to either ask them or check using the management API if they have them,  you could even create them if they don't have them through the management api.     They can always change the name of it manually you know, how will you handle that?

Comment: Then I think I could add a section in my project's back-end CMS where I can add new dimensions & metrics and map their indexes to some webshop-specific settings. Then I could look in the current shop's settings for the correct index of a custom dimension and use that to send values to GA. Sigh... it would have been so sweet if Google also allowed to send the name of the dimension instead of the index.

Comment: Agreed from a programmer standpoint this is a pain,  but its probably easer for Google to do it like this.